# Convertir numero de moneda a letras

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo problemas, estoy usando Tkinter y phpmyadmin en el cual, quiero convertir por ejemplo: "$125.10" a "Ciento Veinticinco Pesos 10/100".
Deseo que en tkinter me genere la conversión para posteriormente colocarla en una columna en phpmyadmin o en su defecto, que no lo muestre en Tkinter pero que si lo registre en phpmyadmin, cual sea de las formas formas, me seria de mucha ayuda.
mis codigos son estos:

```
numero_letras.py

MONEDA_SINGULAR = 'peso'
MONEDA_PLURAL = 'pesos'

CENTIMOS_SINGULAR = 'centavo'
CENTIMOS_PLURAL = 'centavos'

MAX_NUMERO = 999999999999

UNIDADES = (
    'cero',
    'uno',
    'dos',
    'tres',
    'cuatro',
    'cinco',
    'seis',
    'siete',
    'ocho',
    'nueve'
)

DECENAS = (
    'diez',
    'once',
    'doce',
    'trece',
    'catorce',
    'quince',
    'dieciseis',
    'diecisiete',
    'dieciocho',
    'diecinueve'
)

DIEZ_DIEZ = (
    'cero',
    'diez',
    'veinte',
    'treinta',
    'cuarenta',
    'cincuenta',
    'sesenta',
    'setenta',
    'ochenta',
    'noventa'
)

CIENTOS = (
    '_',
    'ciento',
    'doscientos',
    'trescientos',
    'cuatroscientos',
    'quinientos',
    'seiscientos',
    'setecientos',
    'ochocientos',
    'novecientos'
)

def numero_a_letras(numero):
    numero_entero = int(numero)
    if numero_entero > MAX_NUMERO:
        raise OverflowError('Número demasiado alto')
    if numero_entero < 0:
        return 'menos %s' % numero_a_letras(abs(numero))
    letras_decimal = ''
    parte_decimal = int(round((abs(numero) - abs(numero_entero)) * 100))
    if parte_decimal > 9:
        letras_decimal = 'punto %s' % numero_a_letras(parte_decimal)
    elif parte_decimal > 0:
        letras_decimal = 'punto cero %s' % numero_a_letras(parte_decimal)
    if (numero_entero <= 99):
        resultado = leer_decenas(numero_entero)
    elif (numero_entero <= 999):
        resultado = leer_centenas(numero_entero)
    elif (numero_entero <= 999999):
        resultado = leer_miles(numero_entero)
    elif (numero_entero <= 999999999):
        resultado = leer_millones(numero_entero)
    else:
        resultado = leer_millardos(numero_entero)
    resultado = resultado.replace('uno mil', 'un mil')
    resultado = resultado.strip()
    resultado = resultado.replace(' _ ', ' ')
    resultado = resultado.replace('  ', ' ')
    if parte_decimal > 0:
        resultado = '%s %s' % (resultado, letras_decimal)
    return resultado

def numero_a_moneda(numero):
    numero_entero = int(numero)
    parte_decimal = int(round((abs(numero) - abs(numero_entero)) * 100))
    centimos = ''
    if parte_decimal == 1:
        centimos = CENTIMOS_SINGULAR
    else:
        centimos = CENTIMOS_PLURAL
    moneda = ''
    if numero_entero == 1:
        moneda = MONEDA_SINGULAR
    else:
        moneda = MONEDA_PLURAL
    letras = numero_a_letras(numero_entero)
    letras = letras.replace('uno', 'un')
    letras_decimal = 'con %s %s' % (numero_a_letras(parte_decimal).replace('uno', 'un'), centimos)
    letras = '%s %s %s' % (letras, moneda, letras_decimal)
    return letras

def leer_decenas(numero):
    if numero < 10:
        return UNIDADES[numero]
    decena, unidad = divmod(numero, 10)
    if numero <= 19:
        resultado = DECENAS[unidad]
    elif numero <= 29:
        resultado = 'veinti%s' % UNIDADES[unidad]
    else:
        resultado = DIEZ_DIEZ[decena]
        if unidad > 0:
            resultado = '%s y %s' % (resultado, UNIDADES[unidad])
    return resultado

def leer_centenas(numero):
    centena, decena = divmod(numero, 100)
    if numero == 0:
        resultado = 'cien'
    else:
        resultado = CIENTOS[centena]
        if decena > 0:
            resultado = '%s %s' % (resultado, leer_decenas(decena))
    return resultado

def leer_miles(numero):
    millar, centena = divmod(numero, 1000)
    resultado = ''
    if (millar == 1):
        resultado = ''
    if (millar >= 2) and (millar <= 9):
        resultado = UNIDADES[millar]
    elif (millar >= 10) and (millar <= 99):
        resultado = leer_decenas(millar)
    elif (millar >= 100) and (millar <= 999):
        resultado = leer_centenas(millar)
    resultado = '%s mil' % resultado
    if centena > 0:
        resultado = '%s %s' % (resultado, leer_centenas(centena))
    return resultado

def leer_millones(numero):
    millon, millar = divmod(numero, 1000000)
    resultado = ''
    if (millon == 1):
        resultado = ' un millon '
    if (millon >= 2) and (millon <= 9):
        resultado = UNIDADES[millon]
    elif (millon >= 10) and (millon <= 99):
        resultado = leer_decenas(millon)
    elif (millon >= 100) and (millon <= 999):
        resultado = leer_centenas(millon)
    if millon > 1:
        resultado = '%s millones' % resultado
    if (millar > 0) and (millar <= 999):
        resultado = '%s %s' % (resultado, leer_centenas(millar))
    elif (millar >= 1000) and (millar <= 999999):
        resultado = '%s %s' % (resultado, leer_miles(millar))
    return resultado

def leer_millardos(numero):
    millardo, millon = divmod(numero, 1000000)
    return '%s millones %s' % (leer_miles(millardo), leer_millones(millon))
```

Otro modulo.

```
test.py


import unittest
from numero_letras import numero_a_letras, numero_a_moneda


class TestNumeroLetras(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_numero_demasiado_alto(self):
        numero = 1000000000000
        self.assertRaises(OverflowError, numero_a_letras, numero)

    def test_unidades(self):
        numero = 8
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'ocho')
        numero = 2
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'dos')
        numero = 0
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'cero')

    def test_decena_diez(self):
        numero = 15
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'quince')
        numero = 17
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'diecisiete')
        numero = 19
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'diecinueve')

    def test_decena_veinte(self):
        numero = 23
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'veintitres')
        numero = 26
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'veintiseis')
        numero = 21
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'veintiuno')

    def test_menores_cien(self):
        numero = 32
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'treinta y dos')
        numero = 73
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'setenta y tres')
        numero = 89
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'ochenta y nueve')

    def test_centenas(self):
        numero = 167
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'ciento sesenta y siete')
        numero = 735
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'setecientos treinta y cinco')
        numero = 899
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'ochocientos noventa y nueve')

    def test_miles(self):
        numero = 1973
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'mil novecientos setenta y tres')
        numero = 5230
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'cinco mil doscientos treinta')
        numero = 41378
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'cuarenta y un mil trescientos setenta y ocho')
        numero = 197356
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'ciento noventa y siete mil trescientos cincuenta y seis')
        numero = 2004
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'dos mil cuatro')

    def test_millones(self):
        numero = 11852739
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'once millones ochocientos cincuenta y dos mil setecientos treinta y nueve')
        numero = 2000000
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'dos millones')

    def test_millardos(self):
        numero = 1212673201
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'mil doscientos doce millones seiscientos setenta y tres mil doscientos uno')
        numero = 56547567945
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'cincuenta y seis mil quinientos cuarenta y siete millones quinientos sesenta y siete mil novecientos cuarenta y cinco')

    def test_decimales(self):
        numero = 1.87
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'uno punto ochenta y siete')
        numero = 1.50
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'uno punto cincuenta')
        numero = 1.04
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'uno punto cero cuatro')
        numero = 1.00
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'uno')

    def test_negativos(self):
        numero = -4.5
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_letras(numero), 'menos cuatro punto cincuenta')

    def test_moneda(self):
        numero = 1212673201
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_moneda(numero), 'mil doscientos doce millones seiscientos setenta y tres mil doscientos un pesos con cero centavos')
        numero = 56547567945.5
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_moneda(numero), 'cincuenta y seis mil quinientos cuarenta y siete millones quinientos sesenta y siete mil novecientos cuarenta y cinco pesos con cincuenta centavos')
        numero = 1.01
        self.assertEqual(numero_a_moneda(numero), 'un peso con un centavo')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Aqui lo quiero convertir en tkinter:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *


class Formulario:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ventana1=tk.Tk()
        self.ventana1.title("INGRESOS")
        self.cuaderno1 = ttk.Notebook(self.ventana1)
        self.registrar()

        self.cuaderno1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.ventana1.mainloop()

    def registrar(self):
        self.pagina1 = ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
        self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina1, text="Registrar")
        self.labelframe1=ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina1, text="Ingreso")
        self.labelframe1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=10)

#numero
        self.numero=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1,font=("cambria",11),width="30")
        self.numero.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky="w")

#letra
        self.letra=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1,font=("cambria",11),width="30")
        self.letra.grid(column=1,row=2,sticky="w")

#boton
        self.boton1=Button(self.labelframe1,text="CONVERTIR",bg="yellow", height=3,width=15,font=("cambria",11))
        self.boton1.grid(column=1,row=3)

aplicacion1=Formulario()
```

O en su defecto, registrarlo directamente en phpmyadmin justo como lo muestro en las demás columnas.

[image: tabla de registros]

Agradezco de su apoyo y tiempo mas que nada.

Comment: phpmyadmin es solo una interfaz gráfica para administrar la bases de datos de tu servidor, para colocar la etiqueta correcta ¿qué usas MySQL o MariaDB?

Comment: pues no tengo instalado ninguno, yo pensaba que con phpmyadmin podia generar los registros, todo lo he realizado en Tkinter y phpmyadmin, pero sin problema, podria usar MySQL.

Comment: Desde la página principal de phpmyadmin podés ver si la base de datos es MySQL o MariaDB; si no tuvieras un sistema gestor de base de datos instalado, phpmyadmin no estaría funcionando, ya que como te indicaron, es meramente la interfaz gráfica :)

Comment: Si disculpen ya verifique la informacion y la base de datos que uso es: Versión del servidor: 10.4.13-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Answer (score -1):

Yo me basé en un archivo algo diferente y lo subí al repo:

- [Github - wzorroman/numbers_to_letters](https://github.com/wzorroman/numbers_to_letters/tree/master)

Lo pueden consultar para ver mejoras y adaptarlo a lo que tienen.

Comment: No se hasta que punto se puede añadir como respuesta un link a github.. yo creo que seria mejor que añadieras el codigo con su formato correspondiente.